# Xamarin(Android): Image/file format not compatible sharing photo to Instagram

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, instagram, share

I'm trying to share photos to instagram and I have this error 'file format not supported' or 'image format not supported'.

Please, Can anyone help me?

I'm working with Xamarin forms, using a function of the Android Project thanks to DependencyService from the general project.

```
public bool LaunchApp(string path)
        {
            bool result = false;
            String type = "image/*"; 
            String mediaPath = path; 


            try
            {
                // Create the new Intent using the 'Send' action.
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);

                var aUri = Uri.Parse(mediaPath);

                File media = new File(mediaPath);

                // Add the URI to the Intent.
                share.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Uri.FromFile(media));

                // Set the MIME type
                share.SetType(type);

                //var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, aUri);
                Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(share, "Share to"));
                result = true;
            }
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException)
            {
                result = false;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

path = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.BlogsterApp_Ambassador.app/files/Pictures/temp/Screenshot_20190728_222104.jpg" (this path is built with GetGalleryPhotoAsync())
        {

I also trying:

-var aUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(new Uri(mediaPath).ToString());
- share.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, aUri);

Comment: It looks to me like the error is nowhere near any code that sends a file to Instagram.  You seem to be having trouble locally reading the file.  It might be better to concentrate on that (edit your question to make it clear.)  There's probably more people who can help with reading a local file than can help with transferring a file to Instagram.  It can help to mention the ultimate goal of your program as additional information, but you need to explicitly say where the error occurs.

Comment: The ultimate goal of my program is to post a photo on Instagram. I was following this example: https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/ but adapted to Xamarin Forms

Comment: To obtain the photo of my mobile gallery., I use Xam.Plugin.Media in my GetGalleryPhotoAsync()) method.

 **var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions             {                 PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,             });**

file.Path is my mediaPath in the code example

Comment: Is this caused by the format `.jpg`? As the website you post listed, it only support photo format : `jpeg, gif, png`.

Answer (score 0):

```
shareIntent.AddFlags(Android.Content.ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
```

or

```
Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse($"file//:{path}");
```

Could help prevent these errors.